# angular scope not updating in watcher

Tags: angularjs

I have a watch and in that watch I check for some value and then update the other one. This is my code

```
 scope.$watch(function () {
 return userfactory.getUser();
 }, function (newValue, oldValue) {
 if (newValue.User) {


     scope.domainuser = newValue.User.DomainUser;
     scope.isGuardian = scope.domainuser.Category === 'Guardian';

     if (scope.isGuardian && scope.mymessage !== undefined) {
         angular.forEach(newValue.User.DependantUsers, function (value, key) {
             if (scope.mymessage.OnBehalfOf === value.DomainUser.UserName) {
                 scope.mymessage.backGround = globalColorsArray[key];

                 console.log(scope.mymessage);

             }


         });
     }
 }
 });
```

> mymessage is passed from where the directive is called. If I have a function lets say a click button and there if I update the value it does update it.

The strange this is that the console log has the updated property in it. But on the template it doesn't get it.

My template has a lot of stuff but the issue is here

```
<span class="parent-child-color-scheme" ng-show="isGuardian" ng-class="mymessage.backGround"></span>
```

Apparently if I try to update any property it doesn't work inside the watch. It doesn't take effect.

This is what I have in the directive

```
return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            mymessage: "=message",
            frontpage: "=",
            inbox: "="
        }, controller: function ($scope) {
```

Comment: can you show us your template as well?

Comment: updated the code

Comment: strange indeed, you can try to add a `$scope.$apply()` after you change the scope values in watch, but it shouldn't be needed...

Comment: The thing is that I have inbox and outbox, when the app first loads it is in the inbox and it loads correctly. when I click on outbox then it goes to the server and fetch new values. And then it doesn't update anything

Comment: I tried $scope.$apply(), didn't worked

Comment: and I suppose you don't have any errors e.g. in debug console - sometimes this can freeze angular but you don't notice unless you take a look there

Comment: No there are no errors on the console.

Comment: A debugging tip: add `mymessage = {{mymessage | json}}` to your directive template, this will convert the value of the variable to a readible format even if it's a object. And it will change when the variable changes. This way you can quickly see what the problem is.

Comment: it seems like that mymessage inside the watch and in the template have two different scopes. When I update the scope.mymessage inside the watch nothing happens to the template. What bothers me is why it works when I refresh the browser.

Comment: you could try using the `function (newValue, oldValue, scope) {` syntax on the watch to make sure you use the `scope` given by the watch function

Comment: and now it works with passing scope

Comment: if you add that as answer I can approve. :) Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appeared your `scope` inside the `watch` function was referring to a different one than the template's.

If you use the full parameter list of the watch's listener function (as explained [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch)), you can make sure the right scope is used:

```
scope.$watch(function () {
  return userfactory.getUser();
}, function (newValue, oldValue, scope) {
  ...
```

To avoid shadowing with your param name you could even use a different name, e.g:

```
}, function (newValue, oldValue, wScope) {
  ...
  wScope.mymessage.backGround = globalColorsArray[key];
```